# Several logback rolled older files truncated

Tags: java, logback

I have the below logging configuration in my spring boot application.

```
  <appender name="IbkrRollingFile"
      class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOGS}/ibkr.log</file>
    <encoder
        class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/ibkr-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
      </fileNamePattern>
      <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
        <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
      </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
  </appender>
  <!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="IbkrRollingFile" />
  </root>
```

I find that the log files for 08th to 12th have been zeroed out on Feb 13. I also checked the file for 13th Feb and it only contains the log for 13th Feb, not the combined logs for the deleted dates. Why did this happen?

```
   9381 Jan 26 23:45 ibkr-2023-01-26.0.log
  17393 Jan 27 23:45 ibkr-2023-01-27.0.log
  75651 Jan 30 23:45 ibkr-2023-01-30.0.log
 175709 Jan 31 23:45 ibkr-2023-01-31.0.log
 194281 Feb  1 23:45 ibkr-2023-02-01.0.log
 267280 Feb  2 23:52 ibkr-2023-02-02.0.log
 245753 Feb  3 23:34 ibkr-2023-02-03.0.log
    118 Feb  4 04:30 ibkr-2023-02-04.0.log
 386926 Feb  6 21:58 ibkr-2023-02-06.0.log
 415111 Feb  7 23:53 ibkr-2023-02-07.0.log
   4300 Feb  9 10:12 pom.xml
      0 Feb 13 20:40 ibkr-2023-02-12.0.log
      0 Feb 13 20:40 ibkr-2023-02-08.0.log
      0 Feb 13 20:40 ibkr-2023-02-11.0.log
      0 Feb 13 20:40 ibkr-2023-02-10.0.log
      0 Feb 13 20:40 ibkr-2023-02-09.0.log
 468100 Feb 13 23:00 ibkr-2023-02-13.0.log
  15380 Feb 14 12:20 ibkr.log
```

Why at all do older log files get touched let alone truncated?

Comment: I remove the `log4j` tag, since you are using Logback, not Log4j.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quote from this link: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html

**maxHistory    int
The optional maxHistory property controls the maximum number of archive files to keep, asynchronously deleting older files. For example, if you specify monthly rollover, and set maxHistory to 6, then 6 months worth of archives files will be kept with files older than 6 months deleted. Note as old archived log files are removed, any folders which were created for the purpose of log file archiving will be removed as appropriate.
Setting maxHistory to zero disables archive removal. By default, maxHistory is set to zero, i.e. by default there is no archive removal.**

So, try setting property `maxHistory` for your `<rollingPolicy>`. Although according to this quote by default old files should not be deleted. But try setting it to zero to try and disable removal of old files or to some large number to keep up to that number of old files